# Help to understand this proof in Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) on page 105 and I didn't understand this proof:

[image]

1.Why if $R=k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, then $\Omega_k(R)$ is generated (as R-módule) by the differentials $dx_1,\ldots dx_n$?

2.Why if $\Omega_k(K)$ is a vector space of finite dimension over $K$, generated by $dx_1,\ldots,dx_n$ gives us the result?

If someone could help me with some of these questions I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every element of $R$ can be written as $G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for $G\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. But since $d$ is a derivation of $R$ into $\Omega_k(R)$, we have $$d(G(a_1,\ldots,x_n))=\sum_{i=1}^n G_{X_i}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)dx_i.$$ Now every element of $\Omega_k(R)$ is of the form $\sum_i r_i d(s_i)$ for some $r_i\in R$ and some $s_i\in R$ by definition of the module $\Omega_k(R)$. However since we just showed $d(s_j)$ is in the span of the $dx_i$ for all $j$, we have that $\sum_i r_id(s_i)$ is also in the span of the $dx_i$. Thus every element of $\Omega_k(R)$ is in the span of the $dx_i$, or equivalently, $\Omega_k(R)$ is generated as an $R$ module by $dx_1,\ldots,dx_n$.
2. $K$ is the field of fractions of $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ by definition. Since every differential of a fraction can be written in terms of differentials of elements of $R$, $\Omega_k(K)$ is generated as a $K$-module by $dx_1,\ldots,dx_n$, since the differentials of elements of $R$ are. Notice now that a module over a field is called a vector space, and since this is a finitely generated module over $K$, it is a finitely generated vector space over $K$, which implies that it is finite dimensional over $K$.

### Edit:

So the proof is actually just the one sentence following the word *Proof.* In other words, the other paragraphs are just comments that are important when he develops the rest of the material.
Let me see if I can illuminate this proof.

1. First we define $\varphi':F\to M$ by saying $\varphi'(\sum x_i[y_i])=\sum x_i D(y_i)$.
2. Since $D$ is a derivation, for any element $n$ of $N$, $\varphi'(n)=0$. Since the elements of $n$ are just the elements that must map to 0 under *any* derivation. They express the properties of a derivation.
3. Since $\varphi'(N)=0$, and $\Omega_k(R) = F/N$, there is a unique map $\varphi : \Omega_k(R) \to M$ defined by $\varphi(\sum x_i dy_i)=\varphi'(\sum x_i[y_i])=\sum x_iD(y_i)$. Where $[y_i]$ can be any representative of $dy_i$, but in this case we just choose $[y_i]$ for simplicity. This is well defined since any representative of $dy_i$ is of the form $[y_i]+n$ for some $n\in N$, and $\varphi'([y_i]+n)=\varphi'([y_i])+0=\varphi'([y_i])$, so the value of $\varphi$ is independent of any choice of representatives.
4. In particular, we now have $D(x)=\varphi(dx)$ for all $x\in R$.
5. Now that we have shown existence, uniqueness follows since if we have $\varphi(dx)=D(x)$ for all $x\in R$, then $\varphi(\sum x_idy_i)=\sum x_i D(y_i)$, so $\varphi$ is determined completely by this property.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the part 2, what I didn't understand is why the fact $\Omega_k(K)$ is a vector space of finite dimension over $K$, generated by $dx_1,\ldots,dx_n$ implies $D(x)=\varphi (dx)$? Thank you again!!!

Comment: @user42912 sorry, misread that! Let me fix that!

Comment: @user42912 Edited to hopefully better address your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very kind!!! this will help me a lot!

Comment: @user42912 no problem, glad to be helpful!